# Dataframe add column with calculation

Tags: dataframe, loops

I've a Dataframe with multiple columns and trying to add a new column to calculate the sum between these two columns.  Ss there any function can be loop through the whole dataframe?

Original
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMZyI.png)

Desired
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsYaT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why do all columns have the same name?
In pandas, we can create a new column and put the sum of the values of the other two columns in it with the following code:

```
df['sum'] = df['col_1'] + df['col_2']
```

But first you need to change the names of the columns so that they are not the same.
And then you can arrange the columns as desired.

Comment: what if this sum column need to add for col_3 & col_4?  if not hard code, can i use for x in df.columns  something similar to loop through the whole dataframe?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "loop" here, but you can do this for as many columns as you like.